# How to remove BOM (ÿþ) from JGR and Deducer output in JGR console?

Tags: r, output, deducer

I am grateful in advance for the help in removing the BOM from JGR console (analysis by Deducer package). In the output, attached screenshot, I see BOM (ÿþ) and I have tried everything I could find here and on the Web including Control Panel > Region > English (US), updating Java, Encoding using UTF-8 or UTF-16LE, etc.

The only thing that works is that I save the output and open it using RStudio, and using Find and Replace I replace all of BOM instances with nothing. This clears the output and make it readable.[please see screenshot of the output from JGR console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCg26.jpg).

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me getting rid of those unwanted characters in the outputs. Thank you!